# how to authenticate in php with multiple users?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, authentication

I am creating a login page with help of `php` and `mysql` . I am having problem on authenticating when multiple user data stored in database .
Suppose i have table with two user data

```
s.no  username  password
1      user1      1234
2      user2      234
```

when I am giving username and password of first serial no then there is no problem but when i am giving username user1 and password 234 . then user2 is getting authenticated... how to match username and password row wise?? I am providing my backend code.

I tried to print the query result ,it seems its changing username according to password entered.

```
enter code here
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from users where 
username='$username' and password ='$password'")
or die("Failed to connect to database".mysql_error());

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password)  
{   
    if($username=='user1')
    {
        header('Location:htm1/forms.php');
        echo "Login successful!!! Welcome ".$row['username'];
    }
    elseif($username=='user2')
    {
        header('Location:../php/index.php');
    }
else{'
   echo"failed";
}
```

i expect when i enter user1 and password doesn't mach with password of user1 then it should say login failed

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: the above will not work as written. If the user logs in successfully then `header('Location:htm1/forms.php');` will be called and `echo "Login successful!!! Welcome ".$row['username'];` will never execute

Comment: my problem is if i have 2 user id and password ,example[(user1,123) and (user2,2345) ]  on enetring id as user1 and password as 2345 ... user2 data are accessed ...please share the code to differentiate users

Comment: please fix this part of the code `else{'
   echo"failed";
}`

Comment: The code you posted should work the way you expected *"selects only the username `X` that has the password `Y`"* if it didn't select any record, `$row` is going to be `NULL`, are you sure this is the code that you have ? . do `var_dump($row);exit;` after the `mysqli_fetch_array` to see how did the query work.